# assigning value to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is just the outline of the code I am trying.please help me !

```
void surfaceintensity(int xpos,int ypos ,int zpos)
{
    x[1]=xpos;
    x[2]=ypos;
    x[3]=zpos;
}
```

Suppose I have an object t1 and I have sent values to the function surface intensity as:

```
t1.surfaceintensity(10,20,30)
```

If i do it above mentioned way then,will the values of

```
x[1]=10;
x[2]=20;
x[3]=30;
```

If not how can I assign these values to the array `x[]`?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What is the *question*?

Comment: *"I guess there is something wrong"*... be concrete

Comment: "I guess something is wrong" is not a very accurate description of a problem, and posting a huge block of code without even saying what it is supposed to do does not really help either.

Comment: @deviantfan I suspect that the problem is the lack of a code beautifier / indentation

Comment: The part where x[1]=xpos,x[2]=ypos is wrong I guess,couldnt come with correct solution for this problem,I am sorry for not being so good with my question.I hope you understand

Comment: Sorry, we don´t understand. Why you think it´s wrong?

Comment: I have tried to ask the question more clearly, I hope you understand my question!

Comment: As well as I can understand your question, the code you posted does what you seem to think it should. (Ie, everything's fine)

Comment: Arrays (in java!) are 0 indexed, not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your question, you have a class (let's call it `MyClass`) which has a member function `surfaceintensity()`. This member function assigns some values to the elements of an array `x` which is also a member of your class.

You're unsure if assigning values to that array from inside the member function will actually change the array of the instance its called upon. If that is the case, then look at the following example (just copy/paste it, it should compile):

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        x[0] = 0;
        x[1] = 0;
        x[2] = 0;
    }

    void surfaceintensity(int xpos,int ypos ,int zpos)
    {
        x[0]=xpos;
        x[1]=ypos;
        x[2]=zpos;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x[0] << "/" << x[1] << "/" << x[2] << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int x[3];
};

int main()
{
    MyClass t1;
    t1.print();
    t1.surfaceintensity(10,20,30);
    t1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This will print

```
0/0/0
10/20/30
```

This demonstrates that the answer to your question is: yes, assigning values to member variables does change the internal state of the object.

I hope this was what you we're asking. If not, please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: No, it will not work since you (and the original poster) are using index 1..3 instead of 0..2 in surfaceintensity(). Still I do not understand what the problem of the OP is :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, I think our code does what you expect. However you should use array index 0..2 instead of 1..3!